# Batch File that Programatically Compares Two Text Files and Generates Result

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file that runs a program called Windows Compare It! that compares two text files. I know how to run the program and compare but after that I don't know how to invoke the program to save me the results. I have assigned a short cut to saving the report using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Can I make the batch file type that somehow? Or is there another way?

Comment: You could try, but it might be easier to find a tool that could be invoked in a so called 'batch mode', i.e. in a way that required no interaction from the user in order to do its job *and* save the report afterwards. Or maybe the program you are using presently *can* be invoked that way? Using some command-line parameters, maybe?

Comment: Oh interesting. The tool CAN actually do that. I didn't know such a thing even existed. I know, what a N00b.

Comment: The semi-technical term for that requirement is 'programmatically'. May not be a proper word according to purists, but if you say "I need to do X programmatically" in your title, programmers will immediately know what you mean.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0):

(Answer in comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Andriy M wrote:

> You could try, but it might be easier to find a tool that could be invoked in a so called 'batch mode', i.e. in a way that required no interaction from the user in order to do its job and save the report afterwards. Or maybe the program you are using presently can be invoked that way? Using some command-line parameters, maybe?

@Kilian Foth wrote:

> The semi-technical term for that requirement is 'programmatically'. May not be a proper word according to purists, but if you say "I need to do X programmatically" in your title, programmers will immediately know what you mean.